# what is the star symbol for when double clicking a line number in Eclipse Che?

Tags: eclipse-che

In Eclipse Che, when double clicking **on** a line number with code, a star is displayed to the left of the number.  What is the star used for?  Note that this is different than a single click used for flagging a break point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are bookmarks.  When a star is set, a light blue line appears on the right side.  Hovering on the line will display a star and any text on that line.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can then navigate to the bookmarked line by clicking on the icon on the right to the scrollbar.